# Error with a dynamically allocated 2D array

Tags: c, matrix, dynamic-arrays

I have created a small piece of code to dynamically allocate a 2D array in C, this is being used to try and solve a problem I am having on a larger piece of code, if I can get my head around dynamically allocating a 2D array I am confident I will solve my other problem. The issue I have had is that after I have allocated the matrix and wrote to it with a function my program does not run, I do not get any errors, it just creates a blank screen and eventually crashes. I am not sure where to progress from here, any help would be much appreciated!

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void get_matrix(double **a, int n);

int main() {
    int n = 5;
    int i, j;
    double **a;

    a = (double **)malloc(n * sizeof(double *));
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        a[j] = (double *)malloc(n * sizeof(double));

    get_matrix(a, n);

    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j <= n; j++) {
            printf("%d, ", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n, ");
    }
    return 0;
}

void get_matrix(double **a, int n) {
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j <= n; j++) {
            a[i][j] = 4;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42094465/694733)?

Comment: @DavidBowling: strictly speaking, you are correct.  Why not post an answer with c99 code that does allocate and use a 2D VLA? The syntax is somewhat more complicated than the 2D indirect array code posted above.

Comment: @DavidBowling: There were some other problems, I posted a more complete answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- You do not include `<stdio.h>`
- Your loop indexes `i` and `j` run one step too far: since indexing is zero based in C, you must stop before `n` or you will try and access elements outside the array. This bug causes undefined behavior, a plausible explanation for what you observe.
- You pass a `double` for the `%d` `printf` conversion specification. Use `%g` instead.
- You print extra commas at the start of lines.
- Your array is not really a 2D array, it is an indirect array.  In C99, you can allocate and use dynamic arrays with parametric sizes, called VLAs. Look at the syntax below:

Here is an improved version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void get_matrix(int n, double a[n][n]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            a[i][j] = 4;
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int n = 5;
    double (*a)[n] = malloc(sizeof(*a) * n);

    get_matrix(n, a);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            printf("%g, ", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You beat me to it! Just to nitpick, I like to use `malloc(sizeof *a * n)`, placing the `sizeof` expression first by habit. This reduces the chance of overflow when you have more than one multiplication: `malloc(sizeof *a * x * y)`. And I would use `size_t` for `n` and the array indices.

Comment: @DavidBowling: Good point, I usually do the same for exactly the same reason, but I prefer `sizeof(*a) * n` for clarity. I was caught once by `malloc(x * y * sizeof(*p))` with `x` and `y` integers smaller than `size_t`, the overflow is not easy to spot even staring at the code. With a single multiplication, it is not an issue, but consistency is a golden rule.

Comment: Hi there! I have not been able to work on this problem since you last helped me out last week! I have made some changes to how it was written and it runs fine, the only problem being that when I print the matrix it only prints zeros?

Comment: @StevenTaggart: did you change the `printf` format as noted in my answer?

Comment: That's it sorted @chqrlie Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 2):

Problem is in for loop. Your for loop now runs `n + 1` times instead `n` times. This means you are trying to write somewhere on unallocated memory region.

`for (i=0; i<=n; i++)`

should be:

`for (i=0; i<n; i++)`

You have to use conditions *is less* instead of *is less or equal*.

---

While I can see your code, I would also suggest some tricks to avoid later problems by using variables in sizeof directly:

```
a = (double **) malloc (n * sizeof(*a));
```

This will automatically detect `sizeof` of `*a` which is required for allocation size.

Comment: That's it sorted thank you! You've solved a head ache! :)

Comment: Glad to hear ;) If it works for you, you may click "Correct answer" to confirm it.

Answer (score 1):

Your indexes are zero based. This means you check the end condition of a for-loop with a < and not a <=. 0..n-1 are the n locations you allocated.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void get_matrix (double **a, int n);

int main ()

{
    int n = 5;
    int i, j;
    double **a;



    a = (double **) malloc (n * sizeof(double *));
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        a[j] = (double *) malloc (n * sizeof(double));

    get_matrix (a, n);

    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            printf("%d, ", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n, ");
    }

    return 0;

}

void get_matrix (double **a, int n)
{
    int i, j;

    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            a[i][j] = 4;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code has undefined behavior since `a[i][j]` is a `double`, being printed with a `%d` conversion specifier.